# flex FileReference load complete event never fired

Tags: apache-flex, filereference

I have an image which will be uploaded twice by flash. Besides, I'll do some resizing & compression stuff. So I have to load the data and create a BitmapData object.

```
    _fileRef.addEventListener(Event.Complete, onLoadComplete);
    _fileRef.load();
```

The problem is the complete event is never fired which could be checked from log message in console. What are the possibilities that such an event failed to be triggered？

my real code is shown as below:

```
    private function prepareImage():void    
    {
        _compressionFactor = 82;

        if(as3_jpeg_wrapper==null)
        {
            as3_jpeg_wrapper = clibinit.init();
        }
        _fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageComplete);
        _fileRef.load();
    }

    private var tempLoader:Loader;
    private var tempData:ByteArray;

    private function onImageComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        Utils.log("loading data completed");
        tempData = event.currentTarget.data;
        _fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onImageComplete);
        tempLoader =  new Loader;
        tempLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onImageLoaded);
        tempLoader.loadBytes(tempData);
    }
```

The fact is that the log message "loading data completed" is never printed. I've traced the whole process, flash stucked here. The function prepareImage is called via:

```
            Utils.log("We'll resize & compress the picture to be uploaded");
            prepareImage();
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for the [load()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#load()) method of the `FileReference` class. At the bottom, it states that this method can throw two exceptions. It also dispatches 3 other events aside from Event.COMPLETE, in particular IOError.IO_ERROR. I would start by adding a listener for IO_ERROR. Also is this your real code? There is no Event.Complete it's `Event.COMPLETE` :) Consider showing more of your code...

Comment: I attached my real code. I'll try to listen the event IO_ERROR and see what happens

Comment: Is `prepareImage()` called after the user selects the file (ie: called after a `Event.SELECT` is dispatched from the `FileReference`?